# Exclude beforeShowDay when determining maxDate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm "attempting" to create a system at work that allows my students to book equipment. I have two date inputs, for Date of Borrow, and Date of Return. Currently how it is setup, I have a bunch of dates, and the weekends disabled, and, students can't return the gear the day of borrow. The next step I'm attempting is to only offer students a return of the next available day

For instance, a student wants to borrow gear for the weekend but it is also a pupil free day on the Monday, so the Date of Return needs to only be Tuesday.

maxDate: 1 //doesn't take into account all the dates I have disabled from BeforeShowDay

I hope that made sense, here is my current, messy code.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $(function() {

        var publicd = ["4,3", "3,6", ];
        var term1 = ["15,4", "16,4", "17,4", "18,4", "19,4", "22,4", "23,4", "24,4", "25,4", "26,4", ];
        var term2 = ["7,7", "8,7", "9,7", "10,7", "11,7", "12,7", "15,7", "16,7", "17,7", "18,7", "19,7", ];
        var term3 = ["29,9", "30,9", "1,10", "2,10", "3,10", "4,10", "7,10", "8,10", "9,10", "10,10", "11,10"];
        var chrissy = ["2,12", "3,12", "4,12", "5,12", "6,12", "9,12", "10,12", "11,12", "12,12", "13,12", "16,12", "17,12", "18,12", "19,12", "20,12", "23,12", "24,12", "25,12", "26,12", "27,12", "30,12", "31,12", "1,1", "2,1", "3,1", "6,1", "7,1", "8,1", "9,1", "10,1", "13,1", "14,1", "15,1", "16,1", "17,1", "20,1", "21,1", "22,1", "23,1", "24,1", "27,1", "28,1", "29,1", "30,1", "31,1"];
        var pupil = ["8,3", "22,7", "15,11", "9,4", "27,5"];




        var combinedholidays = publicd.concat(term1, term2, term3, chrissy, pupil);

        function TotalHolidays(date) {
          var m = date.getMonth();
          var d = date.getDate();
          var currentdate = d + "," + (m + 1);
          for (var i = 0; i < combinedholidays.length; i++) {
            if ($.inArray(currentdate, combinedholidays) != -1) {
              return [false];
            }
          }
          var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
          return !noWeekend[0] ? noWeekend : [true];
        }


        $("#field_borrow").datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
          minDate: new Date(),
          beforeShowDay: TotalHolidays,
          showOn: "button",
          buttonImage: "https://jccamediaarts.edublogs.org/files/2018/06/if_calendar_285670-copy-2c5zvzr-2o5mcij-e1529025491810.png",
          buttonImageOnly: true,
          buttonText: "Select date",
          onSelect: function(date) {

            var selectedDate = new Date(date);
            var msecsInADay = 86400000;

            var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);


            $("#field_return").datepicker("option", "minDate", endDate);


          }
        });

        $("#field_return").datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
          beforeShowDay: TotalHolidays,
          showOn: "button",
          buttonImage: "https://jccamediaarts.edublogs.org/files/2018/06/if_calendar_285670-copy-2c5zvzr-2o5mcij-e1529025491810.png",
          buttonImageOnly: true,
          buttonText: "Select date"
        });

      }); <
      /script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any specific issues with the code you shown. I have updated it a bit and it seems to work as expected.

```js
$(function() {
  var publicd = ["4,3", "3,6"];
  var term1 = ["15,4", "16,4", "17,4", "18,4", "19,4", "22,4", "23,4", "24,4", "25,4", "26,4", ];
  var term2 = ["7,7", "8,7", "9,7", "10,7", "11,7", "12,7", "15,7", "16,7", "17,7", "18,7", "19,7", ];
  var term3 = ["29,9", "30,9", "1,10", "2,10", "3,10", "4,10", "7,10", "8,10", "9,10", "10,10", "11,10"];
  var chrissy = ["2,12", "3,12", "4,12", "5,12", "6,12", "9,12", "10,12", "11,12", "12,12", "13,12", "16,12", "17,12", "18,12", "19,12", "20,12", "23,12", "24,12", "25,12", "26,12", "27,12", "30,12", "31,12", "1,1", "2,1", "3,1", "6,1", "7,1", "8,1", "9,1", "10,1", "13,1", "14,1", "15,1", "16,1", "17,1", "20,1", "21,1", "22,1", "23,1", "24,1", "27,1", "28,1", "29,1", "30,1", "31,1"];
  var pupil = ["8,3", "22,7", "15,11", "9,4", "27,5"];
  var dtFt = 'yy/mm/dd';

  var combinedHolidays = publicd.concat(term1, term2, term3, chrissy, pupil);

  function isHoliday(day, holidays) {
    var result = false;
    if ($.inArray(day, holidays) >= 0) {
      result = true;
    };
    return result;
  }

  function isWeekend(dt) {
    var result = $.datepicker.noWeekends(dt);
    return !result[0];
  }

  function TotalHolidays(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var currentDate = d + "," + (m + 1);
    var result = [true, "weekDay"];
    if (isHoliday(currentDate, combinedHolidays) || isWeekend(date)) {
      result = [false, ""];
    }
    return result;
  }

  $("#borrow, #return").datepicker({
    dateFormat: dtFt,
    beforeShowDay: TotalHolidays,
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "https://jccamediaarts.edublogs.org/files/2018/06/if_calendar_285670-copy-2c5zvzr-2o5mcij-e1529025491810.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select date"
  });

  $("#borrow").datepicker("option", {
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function(date) {
      var selectedDate = new Date(date);
      var msecsInADay = 86400000;
      var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);
      $("#return").datepicker("option", "minDate", endDate);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Borrow Date: <input type="text" id="borrow" /></p>
<p>Return Date: <input type="text" id="return" /></p>
```

Hope that helps.